# StoreKit 2 Sandbox use can't buy the same subscription again

Tags: ios, storekit, storekit2

My StoreKit 2 tests flow looks like this:

1. Buy subscription lvl 1
2. Buy subscription lvl 2
3. Buy subscription lvl 1

The problem is that when trying to buy the same subscription again with Sandbox user - the iOS dialogs to confirm Payment **are not shown**. `Product.PurchaseResult` in `.success` but if checking in Settings - the subscription is not changed.

What's also interesting: it works if changes directly from System Settings.

Any ideas of what is going on would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever solve it? Did it work once in production?